# Object reference in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small example:

```js
let length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);

$('body').append($('<p>').text('plain text'));
console.log(length);

setTimeout(() => console.log(length), 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My question: after appending, why wouldn't `length` update new value (`1`)? I've tried to delay 1 second before logging, but same result. Why?

Comment: Don't keep `length` in cache. `.length` will return a number which will not automatically change after adding new `p` element. Use `$('body > p').length` each time to get updated no. of `p` elements.

Comment: Because its value is set before you're actually appending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, variables are not re-evaluated whenever you call them. In your case, you set the value of `length` to `0` at the start of your script, and it will remain equal to `0` as long as you don't set it to another value with `length = ...`. So to make your example work, you would need to do:

```
var length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);

$('body').append($('<p>').text('plain text'));
length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `let length = $('body > p').length` was parsed/evaluated  before appending the element.

And after appending the element it is not parsed again.

You can create function & call it

```
function showLength(){
 let length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);
}
```

Also inside `setTimeout` length is not a function which is to be executed

In your code call it

```
showLength();
$('body').append($('<p>').text('plain text'));
showLength();

setTimeout(function(){showLength();}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are storing the old `$('body > p')` element on a variable, and printing the same result two times.

```
let length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);
```

Stores the length of the current `'body > p'`, it dosent exists, then is 0.

```
$('body').append($('<p>').text('plain text'));
console.log(length);
```

You append the new element, but you are printing the OLD element length value, so you get 0 again,  you need to "refresh" the element.

Something like this:

```
let length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);

$('body').append($('<p>').text('plain text'));
length = $('body > p').length;
console.log(length);

setTimeout(() => console.log(length), 1000)
```

Using jQuery when you do something like this:

```
var element = $('element');
```

You are generating an "snapshot" of the element, it means the element is stored on the variable on the moment you declare it. If the element changes but you dont refresh the variable it will return the same values like when you declared it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `length` variable is a number which is a primitive type. In javascript primitives are immutable.

Please take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Data_types